# How can I get and use current multisite email wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress-theming, wordpress

I have a multisite installation in wordpress with a default theme. I have a form on the homepage and want it to send the form data to an email address(the main email for every site created).

I used `get_option('admin_email')` but it uses the general email set in the super admin.

I want to use the email from every new site created.

Is there any whay to set the form to take the current sites email?

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should do it:

```
<?php
if (function_exists('is_multisite') && is_multisite()) 
//checks if it's a multisite
{ 
$admin_email = get_site_option( 'admin_email' ); 
//in multisite, it returns the network-wide site E-mail
} 
else 
{
$admin_email = get_option('admin_email'); 
//gets E-mail address of blog administrator.
}
?>
```

**Documentation:**

[get_site_option](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_site_option)

[get_option](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_option)

Hope his helps. Good luck.